# vault kv put/write binary data

Tags: hashicorp-vault

I have a enc file that I generate using openssl like so.

```
openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -md sha1   -pass file:/tmp/keyfile.key \
                                          -in /tmp/keyfile \
                                          -out /tmp/keyfile.enc
```

I want to store the keyfile.enc file as secret in vault. I tried

```
cat keyfile.enc | vault kv put secret/mysecret key=-
```

Does kv put/write work with binary data ?
I want to use the vault mutating webhook to mount the secret into a container ultimately.

Answer (score 1):

https://discuss.hashicorp.com/t/loading-storing-binary-files-as-secrets/22636

Got my answer. Yes we cannot use binary files, base64 encode them

Comment: How do you get the data back out? I'm trying to use external secrets operator to sync such binary secrets into kubernetes secrets.

Comment: Here's how you do Base64 decoding when injecting value to Kubernetes secret: https://github.com/hashicorp/vault/issues/1423#issuecomment-759596477

    vault.hashicorp.com/agent-inject-template-filename: |
  {{- with secret "secret/jenkins/secretname" -}}{{ base64Decode .Data.data.file }}{{- end }}